# Ajax search when user stops typing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want the ajax to executed when user stops typing but this it isn't working on key up event and when I am putting onkeyup=doneTyping() in input with id searchtext the browser is crashing

```
<script>    
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
var $input = $('#search_text');
 var txt = $(this).val(); 
$input.on('keyup', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

$input.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

function doneTyping () {
     $.ajax({  
                     url:"fetch.php",  
                     method:"post",  
                     data:{search:txt},  
                     dataType:"text",

                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          $('#searchresults').html(data);  
                     }  
              });  

  //do something
}  
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I turned your code into a snippet and added some console logging to show what is going on.

This shows that the events are working exactly as you describe ... and 'Done typing' shows in the console 5 seconds after I quit typing.

```js
var typingTimer; //timer identifier

var doneTypingInterval = 5000; //time in ms, 5 second for example
var $input = $('#search_text');

console.log("$input = ", $input.length);

$input.on('keyup', function() {
  console.log("Key up");
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

$input.on('keydown', function() {
  console.log("Key down");
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

function doneTyping() {
  console.log("Done typing");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Test input: <input id="search_text">
```

Comment: my ajax it doesn't execute

Comment: If your ajax doesn't execute, then that is a question completely unrelated to any of the typing and keyboard handling.  Extract that out . check your Javascript error console .. use the Ajax `error` handler and log any errors that might be happening.